# Listing google drive files in a table

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to find a solution to my problem. I have the google picker installed in the app but I would like to have a listing of all files present in my clients google drive for all users to view in a table. I would like to know if it is possible and if so. Can you please point me in the direction I should head in order to perform the task. Thank you for all your advice and help. For further questions please ask. Example is presented in the bottom. [image: Example table of what I have to do]

Comment: With the picker, the users can select "List View" or "Grid View". For something more specific i think you will need to build your own viewer according to your needs. When you say "a listing of all files" do you mean to list the file in each user account accessible to every user ? or what do you mean?

Comment: "a listing of all files" refers to listing all files within the user google drive. The main task is having a central drive where users are allowed to download/upload files from. Such is the reason for the image shown above. Can you point me in the direction where I may be able to find a solution to listing files for users to access them. Thank you for your advice and reply.